mui DataGrid paginationMeta.hasNextPage not working
Even when I explicitly set the paginationMeta.hasNextPage prop to false:
return (
      <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={rfqCols}
      paginationModel={paginationModel}
      paginationMeta={{hasNextPage: false}}       
      sortingMode="server"
      paginationMode="server"
      onPaginationModelChange={handlePaginationModelChange}
      onSortModelChange={handleSortModelChange}
      rowCount={-1}
      pageSizeOptions={[1,3,5]}
      />
    );

The "next page" button stays active:

What am I missing?  How can I control whether or not the "next page" button is active or disabled?

Ok, instead of setting the rowCount prop every render, I needed to set the initalState.pagination.rowCount prop to initialize the rowCount to -1, then everything worked as expected:
return (
      <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={rfqCols}
        initialState={{ pagination: { rowCount: -1}}}
        paginationModel={paginationModel}
        paginationMeta={paginationMeta}       
        sortingMode="server"
        paginationMode="server"
        onPaginationModelChange={handlePaginationModelChange}
        onPaginationMetaChange={(newMeta) => console.log('newMeta:', newMeta)}
        onSortModelChange={handleSortModelChange}
        pageSizeOptions={[1,3,5]}
      />
    );


It looks like, the creation of the rowCount state variable through the useState hook and passing it to rowCount and onRowCountChange properties works too. In addition, it fixes the MUI X: The 'rowCount' prop must be passed using the "paginationMode='server'" error in the console.

I just spent many hours trying to solve this same problem and I finally figured it out. It's unfortunately not documented, but the button will never become disabled while your 'rowCount' attribute is set to -1.
This means that even if you want to perform server-side fetching with an 'unknown' row count, you still need to be able to know the final total row count when you reach the last page. Once I realized this, I saw that the mock server in the MUI documentation will actually return a 'totalRowCount' value which is actually used as the row count in the demo when the hasNextPage attribute is set to false. It's obviously a major face palm moment since they are trying to demo an 'unknown' row count. It's also fundamentally not intuitive as one would imagine that a self-described attribute like 'hasNextPage' would suffice in determining whether or not there is a next page, but it unfortunately doesn't!
This also means that if you are using a back-end which doesn't ever know the total row count (like DynamoDB for example) you will need to maintain this value yourself in your React app. I used a reference to a map that keeps the page as the key and the row count for that page as the value. I can then reduce this map to get the final row count.
Here is a bit of sample code that you can use to get started in the right direction. You'll need to replace the variables with capital letters with your own values:
return (
  <DataGrid 
    rows={rows} 
    columns={rfqCols}
    paginationModel={paginationModel}
    paginationMeta={{hasNextPage: MY_HAS_NEXT_PAGE}}       
    sortingMode="server"
    paginationMode="server"
    onPaginationModelChange={handlePaginationModelChange}
    onSortModelChange={handleSortModelChange}
    rowCount={MY_HAS_NEXT_PAGE ? -1 : MY_FINAL_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT}
    pageSizeOptions={[1,3,5]}
  />
);


This worked for me! Super weird undocumented behavior, I'd expect hasNextPage to override rowCount. This works better ultimately since it gives appropriate row count in the footer, but still frustrating to spend a few hours figuring this out.
